# How to add mask in a field in the backpack laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

how do I add a mask in a field in the Laravel Backpack Framework. I researched a lot but I could not find any example, I also found no example in the [official documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields) .

I thought of something like it as shows the code below, but it did not work.

```
CRUD::addField([
        'name' => 'cpf',
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'CPF',
        'mask'  => '000.000.000-00',
        'placeholder' => "000.000.000-00", // placeholder 
        'wrapper'  => [
            'class'      => 'form-group col-md-6'
        ]
    ]);
```

Who can help thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i ask 1 thing,
what you mean by mask

Comment: The mask is this, as this link is displayed this link  https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/